# Check if element is on page with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver

I thought doing this

```py
        if driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/button"):
            pass
```

would work, but it doesn't and just returns

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/button"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to do so:

## Using Try / catch

```py
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/button")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Element does not exist")
```

## Using find_elements()

```py
if(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/button")) > 0):
    print("Element exist")
else:
    print("Element does not exist")
```

For more informations see: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/checking-if-element-exists-with-python-selenium

Comment: If I use the first way, the traceback is "element not interactable", because the element is not visible. The second way doesn't seem to work for me, maybe because it's a button (?). I think I would need to check if the element is visible